# H2O.ai Steam launching cluster

Tags: h2o

I'm trying to start a H2O cluster in the Steam web interface. The cluster is starting (I can open it after it started), but Steam thinks it failed and doesn't add it to the list of active clusters. It seems it getting a Java Timeout exception after disowning the cluster. So maybe I need to increase the timeout for the cluster startup?

Is there an option in Steam to increase the timeout? The documentation doesn't say anything about it.

Best regards,

Markus